# Created a slider/swiper i want when arrive to last element continue to first

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

When it reaches the last element, i want it continues to the first, but it repeats from the beginning

```
<div class=" row swiper-container swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal swiper-container-pointer-events" data-sw-autoplay="50" data-sw-loop="true" data-sw-nav-arrows=".features-nav"   loopedSlides= "10"  data-sw-show-items="1"data-sw-space-between="30" data-sw-breakpoints="{&quot;68&quot;: {&quot;slidesPerView&quot;: 3}}">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper px-1" id="swiper-wrapper-265d4fb33cbfda15" aria-live="on">
          

  <div class="swiper-slide px-2 px-sm-1 "
         data-swiper-slide-index="0" role="group" aria-label="">
slider1
                                </div>

  <div class="swiper-slide px-2 px-sm-1 "
         data-swiper-slide-index="0" role="group" aria-label="">
slider2
                                </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide px-2 px-sm-1 "
         data-swiper-slide-index="0" role="group" aria-label="">
slider3
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use `loop:true` in your `swiper` option.

```
config: SwiperOptions = {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 50,
  loop: true,
}
```